# Fetch Dynamic Composite Columns w/o Values - Astyanax

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

To query for DynamicComposite columns, the query goes like this,

```
ColumnFamily<String, DynamicComposite> columnFamilyEntity = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(columnFamily,
                            StringSerializer.get(), DynamicCompositeSerializer.get(), ByteSerializer.get());
        RowQuery<String, com.netflix.astyanax.model.DynamicComposite> rowQuery = keyspace.prepareQuery(columnFamilyEntity).getKey(rowKey);
        com.netflix.astyanax.model.DynamicComposite startRange = getStartComposite(startComponentNames);
        com.netflix.astyanax.model.DynamicComposite endRange = getEndComposite(endComponentNames);
        RangeBuilder rangeBuilder = new RangeBuilder();
        rangeBuilder.setStart(startRange,DynamicCompositeSerializer.get());
        rangeBuilder.setEnd(endRange,DynamicCompositeSerializer.get());
        rangeBuilder.setReversed(reversed);
        rowQuery.withColumnRange(rangeBuilder.build());
ColumnList<com.netflix.astyanax.model.DynamicComposite> queryResultCols = rowQuery.execute().getResult();
```

If I would like to query only the column names (or component names) in DynamicComposite and not the column value, is there a way can I tell the Astyanax client not to query the values?